# Creating a list of sliding images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-image

I'm trying to wrap my head around creating a list of sliding images. I would like to increase this idea and have a list of views, where the view has sliding images and some TextViews.

I understand I have to use a RecyclerView. I also understand I have to use a PagerAdapter. I just don't understand the architecture to combine the two. I can create the code to have sliding images. But I can't create a list of them.

In what order would I go in creating this efficiently?

Comment: I was thinking in regards to how AirBnb has sliding images for each view

Comment: Do i need to have a recyclerview element for each row?